# A program that displays the three-digit numbers that can be divisible by the sum of the first number numbers

Tags: python

```py
jam=0
for i in range(101,1000,2):
    for j in str(i):
        jam+=int(j)
    if i % jam==0:
        print(i)
```

This program just shows `137` and this answer is not true. What is the bug?

Comment: What is *"the sum of the fisrtnumber numbers"*? Anyway, move `jam=0` inside loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop keeps incrementing `jam` and never resets it. `jam` quickly becomes greater than 1000, and after that `i % jam==0` is guaranteed to be `False`. Did you mean to put `jam = 0` *inside* the loop?